# abstract staticmethod throws TypeError when used by subclass instances

Tags: python, class, static-methods, abc

An ABC superclass defines several abstract methods and an abstract static method for which all 3 methods need to be implemented in the subclasses:

```
class Tool(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_this(self) -> None: pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_that(self) -> None: pass

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def name() -> str: pass

class MyTool(Tool):

    def do_this(self) -> None: # do this

    def do_that(self) -> None: # do that

    def name() -> str: return 'MyTool'

>>> MyTool.name()
'MyTool'
>>> MyTool().name()
TypeError: name() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This does not persist if the method `name` in the subclass is decorated with `@staticmethod`.

What is taking place here? Why does this only happen when the superclass is a type of `abc.ABC`?

Using Python 3.6 so use of `abc.staticmethod` is depreciated, but still yields same result.

Comment: You overwrote it with a normal method in the subclass ..

Comment: @wim I thought that might be the case, so I must redeclare the method as a staticmethod in the subclass too? If so, whats the point of the decorator in the superclass?

Comment: Yes. The point of the abstractmethod decorator is to prevent creating `MyTool()` if `MyTool` does not have any `name` method defined.

Comment: @wim I get the point of the `abstractmethod` decorator, I was asking why I needed to use `staticmethod` on both?

Comment: Because there is no magic in Python which passes down the staticmethod declaration from the superclass.  You redefine the method and overwrite it completely. And it's better that way, imagine if we had to check the entire class inheritance chain to know for sure whether a method was decorated or not!

Comment: @wim Fair, then I suppose that changes the question, why do we need to define a the abstract method with `staticmethod` decorator in the superclass at all? If a non-ABC superclass defines a method as static, it is inherited by the sublcasses; if they overwrite it then yes, it goes away.

Comment: @wim I suppose I am curious why the combination of these two decorators doesn't yield a warning that says "You need to define this method as it is abstract, and it also must be a staticmethod".

Comment: You would still want to define that abstract method with staticmethod in the base class, otherwise the method in the base class would have the incorrect arguments (first argument would be implicitly `self`). Then any automatically generated documentation/help text would be misleading. I don't know why combining the two does not make a warning if the derived class deviates, but that sounds complicated to implement and of little utility, so probably nobody bothered.